# install CPAN module

Tags: perl, module, installation, cpan

I have a problem when i want to install perl module
I make " cpan" to install cpan , but i get this "

> Terminal does not support AddHistory.
>
> Your configuration suggests that CPAN.pm should use a working
>   directory of
>     /home/cyrine/.cpan
>   Unfortunately we could not create the lock file
>      /home/cyrine/.cpan/.lock
>      due to permission problems.
>
> Please make sure that the configuration variable
>      $CPAN::Config->{cpan_home}
>   points to a directory where you can write a .lock file. You can set
>   this variable in either a CPAN/MyConfig.pm or a CPAN/Config.pm in your
>   @INC path;
>   You don't seem to have a user configuration (MyConfig.pm) yet.

i make "y" 
then i got this strange message :

> mkdir /home/cyrine/.cpan/CPAN: Permission denied at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN/Shell.pm >line 656

Any idea please?
Thank you

Comment: well, what are the permission for `/home/cyrine/.cpan`? check with `ls -Fal` do you have permission do do what is needed?

Comment: Which linux disro is this (i am guessing Linux since the path is /home)? also are you trying to install modules on to system perl? If it is for system perl it is generally better to use the package manager.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate cause of this problem is that you don't have write permissions on `/home/cyrine/.cpan`.  In my experience, this is most often the result of logging in as a normal user, then running `cpan` for the first time on that account in a `su` session, causing the CPAN configuration to be created in `~cyrine` (because you have cyrine's environment), but owned by root (because `su` has given you root's permissions).  Assuming that is the case, you should be able to resolve this my `su`ing to root, running the command `chown -R cyrine.cyrine /home/cyrine/.cpan` and then running `cpan` as user cyrine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Can you please explain me in details the steps to resolve this problem. Best regards

Comment: `cd /home/cyrine ; su -c chown -R cyrine.cyrine /home/cyrine/.cpan ; cpan`

Comment: @Fredrik Pihl :  drwxr-xr-x   5 root   root         4096 2012-12-15 20:33 .cpan/