# CPAN error message

Tags: cpan

I was trying to use my CPAN, but when I typed in the following command. The errors occurred. A similar question was asked in this forum([install CPAN module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993107/install-cpan-module)), I tried that solution, but it did not work for me. I am wondering if anyone can drop a hint?

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

> Your configuration suggests that CPAN.pm should use a working
>   directory of
>       /home/bq/.cpan
>  Unfortunately we could not create the lock file
>       /home/bq/.cpan/.lock
>  due to 'Permission denied'.
>
> Please make sure that the configuration variable
>       $CPAN::Config->{cpan_home}
>  points to a directory where you can write a .lock file. You can set this variable in either a
>   CPAN/MyConfig.pm or a CPAN/Config.pm in your @INC path;

Comment: The error "Unfortunately we could not create the lock file /home/bq/.cpan/.lock due to 'Permission denied'." is telling you that you don't have permission to write to the `/home/bq/.cpan` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question , but if anyone is still looking. Mine worked with changing the folder permissions for the folder the  i wanted to use.So use chmod to change the folder permission and the modules will install as required.